# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, bower-install

When trying to add a library **symfony/var-dumper** composer long puts packages with bower-asset and in and then gives this error - `[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]                                                                                                No valid bower.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/pammacdotnet/bootstrap-slider.git, could not load a package from it.`
[image]

Comment: Please share the full error message in text form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/issues/329 and your warning message on the beggining of your screenshot I believe you should update your composer in order to fix the warning. I might fix the error itself

Comment: Yes, you're right, but updating the composer itself in a project that has been working on these libraries for a long time is not good, as it turned out you need to update the library with which this problem is associated, in my case it is **dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset**  https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/issues/133#issuecomment-337179853

Comment: I recommend switching to https://asset-packagist.org/ like Yii 2 did.